# Increase year by one in an integer when date is less than today

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date column that's type is an integer. The date is recorded as `YYYYMMDD`. How can I extract just the year and increase it by one if the entire date in that record is before today i.e. historical?

**Example scenario:** This 202**2**0129 becomes 202**3**0129.

I tried this but it overwrote the whole thing just the year `YYYY`, and not the rest of the date:

```
UPDATE table SET enddate = DATE_ADD(enddate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) WHERE enddate < CURDATE()
```

I'm guessing `DATE` needs to be used, just not sure how exactly.

Comment: Don't store dates as integers. Use a date/datetime column and use `year()` to extract the year when needed.

Comment: `enddate = endate + 10000`?

Comment: If you converted `enddate` to a DATE data type then your query would have worked. So why are you storing dates as integers

Comment: @user3783243 why? it's perfect valid

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Storing as `Tuesday.Novem.1.5.2022.08.35.30` also is "valid" but I'd hate to have to work with that data format as well. Use the data type designed for the data being stored, `varchar`/`text` for string, `date`/`datetime` for date, one of the `int`s for integers, etc... or if you are referencing epoch/timestamp storage that is not what OP is using here.

Comment: @user3783243 the type should thinked be not in the data itself, instead in what do you need to do with the data. There are some cases that a number as a code should be defined as string for scalability pourposes, and date as integer or long for unixstamp can avoid 2038 problems, index and reorder and as in this case, major update.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I love the simplicity.